# Webpack conditional compilation with wrapper

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to implement conditional compilation.
I use the EnvironmentPlugin to achieve this. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/#root
The goal is to make webpack remove unused code from the final bundle.

The following works. calculation() is not being called and therefore it is not included.

```
if(process.env.MY_VARIABLE === 'some_value') {
  calculation()
}
```

But this does not:

```
const check = process.env.MY_VARIABLE === 'some_value'
if(check) {
  calculation()
}
```

Is there a way to make webpack think harder? `check` is a const variable, the value can't be changed to something different. So this should work.
I'm still using webpack 4. Is it possible this might work in webpack 5?